# Continuous SubForm Output based on Combobox Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010, continuous-forms

I'm trying to get a continuous subform, displaying CourseID and CourseCompletionDate, to display output related to the Employee chosen in through the main subform's combobox (this is an employee training profile showing what the employee's completed training on). Here's my VBA:

```
Private Sub cboEmployee_AfterUpdate()
    On Error GoTo Proc_Error
    If IsNull(Me.cboEmployee) Then
       Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.EmployeeProfile.Filter = ""
       Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.EmployeeProfile.FilterOn = False
    Else
      Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.EmployeeProfile.Filter = "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboEmployee
      Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.EmployeeProfile.FilterOn = True
    End If
Proc_Exit:
       Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
       MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in setting subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
       Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

Error that I get when trying to use the combobox on the main subform.
[image: Error that I get when trying to use the combobox on the main subform]

Why doesn't this want to work when switching employees in the combobox? How can I make this VBA and subform work flawlessly with the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

So, in addition to what pteranodon stated, adding the employeeID to the query itself fixed everything. No more message box, and the combobox works perfectly with the subform.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: (please correct):

`EmployeeProfile` is the name of the **form** that you invoke as a subform.
`subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion` is the name of the **subform control** in your main form that has its SourceObject set to `EmployeeProfile`.

The syntax you are looking for is

Me.subformcontrol.Form.FormProperty
so
`Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter = ""`

But actually, it looks like you can acheive this without code at all by setting the subform control's LinkMasterFields to `cboEmployee` and LinkChildFields to `EmployeeID`. You can then decide on how to set Filter on Empty Master. All of these properties are on the Data tab of properties window when the subform control is selected (single click).

Comment: LinkMaster wasn't working properly so I found it easier to code this up.

Comment: It works a bit better now, but I have some new issues:

1. Upon choosing an employee from the combobox, a dialog box pops up asking me to enter an employeeID number. This is a hidden value in the combo box that it should automatically pull from.
2. The data in the subform control isn't pulling from the data tables correctly. I select one employee that outputs all of the records. Upon selecting the other employees, there are no records. The employee that shows all of the records correlates to the employeeID I enter into the dialog box.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Make sure you've cleared both LinkMaster/LinkChild fields (may cause the prompt you see). Please add `Debug.Print Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter` after the FilterOn=True line. That will help you make sure you are filtering by the EmployeeID and not the EmployeeName if it is a multi-column combobox.

Comment: The linkMaster/linkChild fields are clear, and I added the line of text you suggested, but I'm still seeing the prompt and the filter is still not filtering based on the employeeID (first, last name) chosen in the combobox. Any ideas?